# How to optimize MySQL VIEW performance?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, view

All my years of development an this is my first post, so I hope I get this right.

I hoping someone can help, my SQL skill is sufficient enough to get me by most of the time, but I'm having poor performance with this view, I know why but I can seem to think of the solution.

My goal is to calculate the total shift time for a given request day, that is the total time of all the users shifts on the date of the request. I then also need the total time of the shifts booked. Becasue a user could have a multiple shifts in the day the request may only be for some of the shifts (half day holiday) and I need to calculate the difference of total worked vs total booked. For example a user could have a morning shift 09:00 - 12:00 and an evening shift 17:00 - 18:00, the user requests the moringin shift as a holiday the `shift_day_hours` would be 4 and the `hours_percent_of_day_rounded` would be 1.0 becuase they have taken more than half of their total time off.

- A `user`(staff) has many `rota` through `staff_rota` becuase they can have multiple shifts on the same day. the `rota` has the start and end date of the rota.
- A `user`(staff) has many `staff_holidays` which below to a single `request`
- A specifc `staff_rota` belongs has many `staff_holidays` through `staff_holidays_rota_staff`

I know my performance hit is the `LEFT JOIN` that has the sub select becuase im querying all the reconds in the `rota` table becuase I need the `rota` date and this is joining all the rota rows when only need the dates that coincide with the request. A the two key bits of info are split between two tables with 200-300k records. If a holiday accounts for more then 0.5 of the day then is rounds up to a full day.

Here is the query for my `view`

```
SELECT 
    staff_holidays.user_id,
    staff_holidays.request_id,
    staff_holidays.date,
    ANY_VALUE(day_hours.shift_day_hours) AS shift_day_hours,
    IF(SUM((ROUND((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                                 rota.start,
                                 rota.end) / 60),
                  2) / day_hours.shift_day_hours)) > 0.5,
       1,
       0.5) AS hours_percent_of_day_rounded
FROM staff_holidays
LEFT JOIN users ON staff_holidays.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN request ON staff_holidays.request_id = request.id
LEFT JOIN staff_holidays_rota_staff ON staff_holidays.id = staff_holidays_rota_staff.staff_holidays_id
LEFT JOIN rota_staff ON staff_holidays_rota_staff.rota_staff_id = rota_staff.id
LEFT JOIN rota ON rota_staff.rota_id = rota.id
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    rota_staff.user_id AS user_id,
    rota.date AS date,
    SUM(ROUND((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, rota.start, rota.end) / 60), 2)) AS shift_day_hours
    FROM rota
    LEFT JOIN rota_staff ON rota.id = rota_staff.rota_id
    WHERE ISNULL(rota.deleted_at) 
    AND (ISNULL(rota_staff.deleted_at) OR ((rota_staff.deleted_at IS NOT NULL) AND (rota_staff.holiday_id IS NOT NULL)))
    GROUP BY rota_staff.user_id , rota.date
) day_hours ON day_hours.date = staff_holidays.date AND day_hours.user_id = staff_holidays.user_id
WHERE shift_day_hours is not null
group by 
staff_holidays.user_id, 
staff_holidays.request_id, 
staff_holidays.date;
```

`EXPLAIN` result

[image: enter EXPLAIN result]

Here is the query for my `view`

[image]

Thanks in advance

**update info**

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
  "id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "uuid" char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  "forename" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  "surname" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  "email" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  "password" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "password_token" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "remember_token" varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "type_id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  "address_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "status_id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  "last_login" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_by" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_by" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "deleted_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "primary_contact" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  "secondary_contact" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "messaging_token" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "is_super_admin" tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  "app_first_login" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "full_name" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(`forename`,_utf8mb4' ',`surname`)) VIRTUAL,
  "main_area_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "exceptions" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "notifications" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "exceptions_start_date" date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  UNIQUE KEY "users_email_unique" ("email"),
  KEY "users_type_id_foreign" ("type_id"),
  KEY "users_address_id_foreign" ("address_id"),
  KEY "users_status_id_foreign" ("status_id"),
  KEY "users_uuid_index" ("uuid"),
  KEY "users_main_area_id_foreign" ("main_area_id"),
  CONSTRAINT "users_address_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("address_id") REFERENCES "address" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "users_main_area_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("main_area_id") REFERENCES "area" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "users_status_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("status_id") REFERENCES "user_status" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "users_type_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("type_id") REFERENCES "user_type" ("id")
)

CREATE TABLE "rota" (
  "id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "date" date NOT NULL,
  "start_time" time NOT NULL,
  "end_time" time NOT NULL,
  "notes" text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  "cleaners_required" int NOT NULL,
  "lone_worker" int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "status_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "site_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_by" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_by" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "deleted_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "rota_config_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "start" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "end" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "site_shutdown" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "no_resource" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "cover_rota_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "covered_rota_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  KEY "rota_status_id_foreign" ("status_id"),
  KEY "rota_site_id_foreign" ("site_id"),
  KEY "rota_rota_config_id_foreign" ("rota_config_id"),
  KEY "rota_date_start_end_index" ("date","start","end"),
  KEY "rota_cover_rota_id_foreign" ("cover_rota_id"),
  KEY "rota_covered_rota_id_foreign" ("covered_rota_id"),
  KEY "rota_deleted_at_index" ("deleted_at"),
  CONSTRAINT "rota_cover_rota_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("cover_rota_id") REFERENCES "rota" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "rota_covered_rota_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("covered_rota_id") REFERENCES "rota" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "rota_rota_config_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("rota_config_id") REFERENCES "rota_config" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "rota_site_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("site_id") REFERENCES "site" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "rota_status_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("status_id") REFERENCES "rota_status" ("id")
)

create index rota_date_deleted_at_index
    on rota (date, deleted_at);

create index rota_date_start_end_index
    on rota (date, start, end);

CREATE TABLE "rota_staff" (
  "id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "rota_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "user_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "clock_in" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "clock_out" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_by" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_by" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "deleted_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "manual_clock_in" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "manual_clock_out" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  "has_issue_logged" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "clock_in_location_data" json DEFAULT NULL,
  "clock_out_location_data" json DEFAULT NULL,
  "holiday_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "clock_in_distance" decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  "clock_out_distance" decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  "missed_override" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "completed" tinyint(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if((`missed_override` = 1),1,if(((`clock_in` is not null) and (`clock_out` is not null)),1,if(((`manual_clock_in` is not null) and (`manual_clock_out` is not null)),1,0)))) VIRTUAL,
  "site_shutdown" tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  KEY "rota_staff_rota_id_foreign" ("rota_id"),
  KEY "rota_staff_user_id_foreign" ("user_id"),
  KEY "rota_staff_holiday_id_foreign" ("holiday_id"),
  KEY "deleted_at" ("deleted_at"),
  KEY "deleted_at_2" ("deleted_at","holiday_id"),
  CONSTRAINT "rota_staff_holiday_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("holiday_id") REFERENCES "staff_holidays" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "rota_staff_rota_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("rota_id") REFERENCES "rota" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT "rota_staff_user_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "users" ("id")
)

create index rota_staff_holiday_id_foreign
    on rota_staff (holiday_id);

create index rota_staff_rota_id_foreign
    on rota_staff (rota_id);

create index rota_staff_user_id_foreign
    on rota_staff (user_id);

CREATE TABLE "staff_holidays" (
  "id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "date" date NOT NULL,
  "status" enum('pending','rejected','approved') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
  "created_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "request_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "user_id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  "shift_ids" json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  KEY "staff_holidays_request_id_foreign" ("request_id"),
  KEY "staff_holidays_user_id_foreign" ("user_id"),
  KEY "date" ("date","user_id"),
  CONSTRAINT "staff_holidays_request_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("request_id") REFERENCES "request" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "staff_holidays_user_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "users" ("id")
)

create index staff_holidays_request_id_foreign
    on staff_holidays (request_id);

create index staff_holidays_user_id_foreign
    on staff_holidays (user_id);



CREATE TABLE "staff_holidays_rota_staff" (
  "id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "staff_holidays_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "rota_staff_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  KEY "staff_holidays_rota_staff_staff_holidays_id_foreign" ("staff_holidays_id"),
  KEY "staff_holidays_rota_staff_rota_staff_id_foreign" ("rota_staff_id"),
  CONSTRAINT "staff_holidays_rota_staff_rota_staff_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("rota_staff_id") REFERENCES "rota_staff" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "staff_holidays_rota_staff_staff_holidays_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("staff_holidays_id") REFERENCES "staff_holidays" ("id")
)

create index staff_holidays_rota_staff_rota_staff_id_foreign
    on staff_holidays_rota_staff (rota_staff_id);

create index staff_holidays_rota_staff_staff_holidays_id_foreign
    on staff_holidays_rota_staff (staff_holidays_id);

CREATE TABLE "request" (
  "id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  "requested_by_id" bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  "actioned_by_id" bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  "type" enum('holiday','sickness','maternity','bereavement','AWOL','unpaid') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  "note" text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  "created_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "deleted_at" timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  "status" enum('pending','rejected','pending-approval','approved') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
  "created_by" text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  KEY "request_requested_by_id_foreign" ("requested_by_id"),
  KEY "request_actioned_by_id_foreign" ("actioned_by_id"),
  CONSTRAINT "request_actioned_by_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("actioned_by_id") REFERENCES "users" ("id"),
  CONSTRAINT "request_requested_by_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY ("requested_by_id") REFERENCES "users" ("id")
)

create index users_address_id_foreign
    on users (address_id);

create index users_main_area_id_foreign
    on users (main_area_id);

create index users_status_id_foreign
    on users (status_id);

create index users_type_id_foreign
    on users (type_id);

create index users_uuid_index
    on users (uuid);
```

`EXPLAIN` text output

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | staff_holidays | NULL | ALL | staff_holidays_user_id_foreign,date | NULL | NULL | NULL | 17446 | 100.00 | Using temporary |
| 1 | PRIMARY | users | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | staff_holidays.user_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | request | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | staff_holidays.request_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | PRIMARY | staff_holidays_rota_staff | NULL | ref | staff_holidays_rota_staff_staff_holidays_id_foreign | staff_holidays_rota_staff_staff_holidays_id_foreign | 9 | staff_holidays.id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | rota_staff | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | staff_holidays_rota_staff.rota_staff_id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY | rota | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | rota_staff.rota_id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | NULL | ref | <auto_key1> | <auto_key1> | 12 | staff_holidays.user_id,staff_holidays.date | 16 | 90.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DERIVED | rota | NULL | ref | rota_deleted_at_index | rota_deleted_at_index | 5 | const | 128091 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
| 2 | DERIVED | rota_staff | NULL | ref | rota_staff_rota_id_foreign | rota_staff_rota_id_foreign | 9 | rota.id | 1 | 82.90 | Using where |

Comment: Welcome to dba.SE.  Can you provide the `EXPLAIN` plan in text, and the relevant table DDL with any indexes/keys defined?

Comment: @bbaird thank you, I realy appreciate the reply. I have updated and added the DLLs.

Comment: Thanks for the DDL. 

In this context, "provide the EXPLAIN plan in text" means to paste into your question the text (that is, *not* an image) from the MySQL EXPLAIN statement (or EXPLAIN ANALYZE statement). Docs are [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan).

Comment: Just curious: did *you* write the SQL, or did an ORM write the SQL?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I'm using Laravel, so this all a result of the migration scripts.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' text EXPLAIN added. Cheers

Comment: I was thinking of adding the rota date to the rota_staff table that way I wouldn't need to join the rota table just to get the date. I only need the date to get to the rota_staff. But then that means breaking normal form.

Comment: Change `ISNULL(rota.deleted_at)` to `rota.deleted_at IS NULL` (and similar cases)

Comment: It seems that `LEFT` is not called for.  Please remove it except where the 'right' table is truly optional.

Comment: Try `JOINing` to `rota` instead of having it in a derived table.